# Using Regexp to check whether a string starts with a consonant

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a better way to write the following regular expression in Ruby? The first regex matches a string that begins with a (lower case) consonant, the second with a vowel.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to write a regular expression that matches the negative of the second expression, versus writing the first expression with several ranges.

```
string =~ /\A[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/
string =~ /\A[aeiou]/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The statement

```
$string =~ /\A[^aeiou]/
```

will test whether the string starts with a *non-vowel* character, which includes digits, punctuation, whitespace and control characters. That is fine if you *know* beforehand that the string begins with a letter, but to check that it starts with a consonant you can use forward look-ahead to test that it starts with both a letter and a non-vowel, like this

```
$string =~ /\A(?=[^aeiou])(?=[a-z])/i
```

To match an arbitrary number of consonants, you can use the sub-expression `(?i:(?![aeiou])[a-z])` to match a consonant. It is atomic, so you can put a repetition count like `{3}` right after it. For example, this program finds all the strings in a list that contain three consonants in a row

```
list = %w/ aab bybt xeix axei AAsE SAEE eAAs xxsa Xxsr /

puts list.select { |word| word =~ /\A(?i:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){3}/ }
```

**output**

```
bybt
xxsa
Xxsr
```

Comment: How would you match for multiple characters? For instance if you wanted to find if the first 3 letters were consonants, with the {3} after the expression?

Comment: @EMK428: My apologies - I lapsed into Perl! I have modified my answer to show how to match use a repetition count on a "consonant" sub-expression.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the answer provided by @Alexander Cherednichenko in order to get rid of the if statements.

```
/^[^aeiou\W]/i.match(s) != nil
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch a string that doesn't start with vowels, but only starts with consonants you can use this code below. It returns true if a string starts with any letter other than A, E, I, O, U. **s** is any string we give to a function

```
  if /^[^aeiou\W]/i.match(s) == nil
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
```

**i** added at the end to make regular expression case insensitive.

**\W** is used to catch any non-word character, for example if a string starts with a digit like: "1something"

**[^aeiou]** means a range of character except **a e i o u**

And we put **^** at the beginning before **[** to indicate that the following range **[^aeiou\W]** if for the 1st character

Answer (score 0):

Note that `^[^aeiou\W]` pattern is not correct because [it also matches a line that starts with a digit, or underscore](https://rubular.com/r/dUWW1AB3T3jO8I). [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407068/3832970)'s solution is working well, but there is one more possible solution *without lookaheads*, based on [*character class subtraction*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) ([more here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction)) and using the more contemporary [`Regexp#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F):

```rb
/\A[a-z&&[^aeiou]]/i.match?(word)
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/bD8yrdcLqCUsoK).

**Details**

- `\A` - start of a string (`^` in Ruby is start of any line)
- `[a-z&&[^aeiou]]` - an `a-z` character range matching any  ASCII letter (`/i` flag makes it case insensitive) *except for* the `aeiou` chars.

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/D6xcKT):

```rb
test = %w/ 1word _word ball area programming /
puts test.select { |w| /\A[a-z&&[^aeiou]]/i.match?(w) }
# => ['ball', 'programming']
```