# Combine two regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, syntax

I want to return `true` if a string starts with a consonant. I have two conditions and don't know how to combine them.

1) it is a letter
2) it is not a vowel

```
!!(s[0] =~ /([a-z]&&[^aeiou])/i)
```

I tried all sorts of other syntax like:

```
!!(s[0] =~ /([a-z])([^aeiou])/i)
!!(s[0] =~ /(([a-z])([^aeiou]))/i)
```

is there any way to do this in one regex? Do I need to check each condition separately?

Comment: What is it with all these "consonant" questions lately? For instance, "[using regexp to check whether a string starts with a consonant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406509/using-regexp-to-check-whether-a-string-starts-with-a-consonant)"
and "[if statement in ruby using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214270/if-statement-in-ruby-using-regex)". There are lots more if you [search Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+consonant).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the character classes using the `&&` operator:

```
/[a-z&&[^aeiou]]/
```

Note that the `&&` operator is used *inside* the character class, not afterwards.

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes):

> A character class may contain another character class. By itself this
>   isn’t useful because `[a-z[0-9]]` describes the same set as `[a-z0-9]`.
>   However, character classes also support the `&&` operator which
>   performs set intersection on its arguments. The two can be combined as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> /[a-w&&[^c-g]z]/ # ([a-w] AND ([^c-g] OR z))
> # This is equivalent to:
> /[abh-w]/
> ```

Comment: why does it not end with the statement that it's equivalent to `/[abh-wz]/`?  What happened to the `z`?  Why would it be excluded when it wasn't a part of the negated class (`[^c-g]`)?

Comment: @iconoclast because it's a set intersection between `[a-w]` and `[[^c-g]z]`. Note the parentheses in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a look ahead to check that the string starts with both a letter and consonant.

```
\A(?=[^aeiou])(?=[a-z])
```

Or use a negative look ahead.

```
(?i:(?![aeiou])[a-z]\w*)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You would need to follow the look-aheads with something to actually match (such as `.` or `\w`), and then the look-aheads combine as though it were an `&&`. Also, a negative look-ahead such as `(?![aeiou])` functions sort of as an "and-not".

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i
```

Not much longer than the fancier options.